# Travel time from Burj Khalifa observation deck to DXB Terminal 3 without taxi

Tags: airport-transfer, dubai, dxb

Would anyone know how long it takes to travel from Burj Khalifa's observation deck to Dubai International Airport (DXB) Terminal 3 check-in counters by Metro and foot on a Saturday evening in January?

If not, just the travel time from the Burj Khalifa/Dubai Mall Metro station to the Terminal 3 Metro station will do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The elevator ride down should be less than two minutes, but there may be lines getting in.

There are buses between Dubai Mall and the Burj Khalifa metro station, but from the Burj Khalifa itself to the station it is quicker to walk. Google maps shows a 25min walking route, but I remember by jaywalking, it was more like 10-15min.

The metro train frequency is between 3 and 8 minutes, the ride to the airport takes about 26min.

At the airport the metro station is pretty close to the terminal, you wont need more than 10 minutes to the check-in counters.

So I would plan for at least an hour, 90min to be safe.

Comment: The queue for the lift down after sunset is seriously long! At the bottom, there is an exhibition on the building which might take about half an hour to see. Even if one doesn't see it, walking through it to Dubai Mall takes another 10 mins or so.